# Laravel resource: Get some of relations

Tags: laravel

There is a model `User` and a model `Payments`. I need to create a resource such that returns user with successful payment which is identified by a `status` fields. This is my solutions:

```
class User extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory, SearchableTrait, SortableTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'username', 'hash_id'];
    public $searchable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'id', 'user:referred'];
    public $sortable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'id'];

    protected $table = 'users';


    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class,'user_id');
    }
}
```

and in controller

```
public function index()
{
    $users = new User();
    $users = $users::with(['invoices'])->filtered()->sorted();
    return UserResource::collection($users->paginate());
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Transformers;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{  

public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'mobile' => $this->mobile,            
        'invoices' => count($this->invoices()->where('status', 2999)->get()),            
    ];
}
}
```

and model

```
class Invoice extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'payment_invoices';


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function scopeSuccessful($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 2999);
    }
}
```

It seems to be messy solution. I am looking for something to use the scope inside the model relation inside the resource. How can I do that?

Comment: `$users = new User();` You're creating a new user here, does a new user have invoices? (Btw, I'd name it `$user` instead of `$users` since it only is really _one_ user)

Comment: @kerbh0lz it returns all users in paginate

Answer (score 1):

in your controller you can just do this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

public function index()
{
    $users = User::with(['invoices'])->whereHas('invoices', function(Builder $query) {
      $query->where('status', 2999);
    });
    return UserResource::collection($users->paginate());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class User extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory, SearchableTrait, SortableTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'username', 'hash_id'];
    public $searchable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'id', 'user:referred'];
    public $sortable = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'id'];

    protected $appends = ['success_payments']; // append this value in all queries    

    protected $table = 'users';


    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class,'user_id');
    }

    //the function for it
    public function getSuccessPaymentsAttribute(){
        return App\Payment::where('user_id', $this->id)->where('status', 'success')->get(); //replace the attribute name or condition as per your db structure
    }
}
```

You can use this in your User Model.